# simple linux script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm having problems creating an automated script to isntall solr on a new server

```
sudo cp "apache-solr-3.3.0/dist/apache-solr-3.3.0.war" "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr.war"
sudo cp -R "apache-solr-3.3.0/example/solr/" "/var/lib/tomcat6/solr/"
sudo cp "solr.xml" "/etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml"
rm -R "apache-solr-3.3.0"
sudo service tomcat6 restart
```

I get

```
cp: target `\r' is not a directory
cp: target `\r' is not a directory
rm: cannot remove `\r': No such file or directory
 * Usage: /etc/init.d/tomcat6 {start|stop|restart|try-restart|force-reload|status}
```

It seems because I use line breaks to terminate the commands (as if it were a windows bat file).  How do I run multiple commands in a single file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably using Windows line breaks in your script. Convert them to Linux line breaks with the `dos2unix` utility: `dos2unix your_script.sh`

Comment: or with dos2unix I used  cat oldfild | tr '\n\r' '\n\n' >> newfile

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be that your shell script has windows line endings (`\r\n`). Bash only cares about the `\n` and so the `\r` is interpreted as being a part of the command.

You need to change the line endings to unix (`\n` only). `dos2unix` can do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Correct the line endings in your script to use the unix standard `\n`. Unfortunately you have `\r`s there as well and it looks like the shell passes them as last arguments.